# Transient Fault Handling For Reliable Connection On DataContext

Tags: linq-to-sql, azure-sql-database, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service that uses a DBML file to generate all the code required for my DataContext. My database is running on the SQL Azure Business tier (so still using the shared model) and I am using the Transient Fault Handling Application Block to wrap all my calls.

The problem I'm seeing is that I'm still getting a number of SqlExceptions around "timeout expired". My retry policy hooks into the Retrying event to log any retries but i never see anything in my logs except the timeout exception.

From my research it looks like the Retry block only retries the query and assumes it has a reliable connection. However, since i'm using a DataContext I don't actually have control of setting up that connection and since all my existing code is Linq2Sql I don't want to switch it.

Am I missing something simple? There doesn't seem to be any way to tell the DataService that the CurrentDataSource should be a reliable connection or anyway to use the RetryManager to use a policy on the connection itself.

Here's an example of one of my ServiceOperations:

```
[WebGet]
    public MyTable GetDetailsById(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var detail = retryPolicy.ExecuteAction<MyTable>(() =>
                CurrentDataSource.MyTable
                .Where(l => l.id == id)
                .FirstOrDefault());

            return detail;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Update: My query doesn't take longer than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Command timeouts occur when the client is not getting a response from the server within x amount of seconds. The is not a transient error and hence not handled by the retry logic. The general recommendation is to change the command timeout to at least 30 seconds for Azure SQL Database. In addition, if you have long running queries, you should consider to increase the timeout for these queries beyond your application wide default.

Documentation on how to set the command timeout can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: For argument's sake lets say the query doesn't take longer than 30 seconds. The question still stands, how do i get a reliable connection with L2S using a DataContext?